# Mapping Subsets to Unique Numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I have set to which I want to map unique numbers to all its subsets. So a function $f(x)$ such that $f$ is 1:1.

Here's the set, but I imagine the method to do this can be generalized - I'd like this one to be used as an example though.

Pick a $n$ such that $n \in\mathbb{N}$
$$S_n = \{(x, y) : x < n,\space y = \{0, 1\},\space x \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

An example of the set if $n=2$ looks like this:
$$S_2=\{(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0),(1, 1)\} $$

So $f(x) \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in P(S_n)$ where $P$ is the power set function.

An example could be something like:
$$f(\emptyset) = 0$$ 
or like this:
$$f(\{(2, 1),(3,0)\}) = 10$$

Thank for the help!

For context, I'm working on a hashing algorithm for a game, and the elements I need to hash have a similar structure to a subset of $S$.

Comment: For hashing, rather use a standard builtin hash function of your object (or of something like json_encode of it)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So, if I were to use the standard builtin hash function, the program would use the pointer and hash that. The problem is that pointers don't contain any information about contents of an object. Two different pointers to two different objects but with equal contents is a definite possibility, and I want my hash to handle that possibility.

On the other hand, any encoding that requires more than O(1) to check equality is far too expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $A$ as $\{(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), \ldots ,(x_k,y_k)\}$; each $x_i \in \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ and each $y_i \in \{0,1\}$.

Then set $f(A) = \sum_{i=1}^k 2^{2(x_i-1) +y_i}$.

**If instead each $x_i \in \{0,2,\ldots, n-1\}$ and everything else as before then set $f(A) = \sum_{i=1}^k 2^{2x_i +y_i}$.

The idea is that the binary expansion of $f(A)$ gives $A$ explicitly: For each ordered pair $(x,y) \in S_n$, the element $(x,y)$ is in $A$ iff the $[2(x-1)+y]$-th bit of $f(A)$ is 1. [Given $(x,y),(x',y') \in S_n$, note that $2(x'-1)+y' \not = 2(x-1)+y$ iff $(x,y) \not = (x',y')$.]

Comment: This is nice! Note that $x_i$ may be zero, so you should probably remove the $(x_i - 1)$ part.

Comment: Sure. My understanding is that $x_i \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$. In any case I did edit in case $x_i \in \{0,1,\ldots, n-1\}$.